# Проблема с Живой Лентой при загрузке сообщений

Tags: битрикс

Проблема в том, что в живой ленте - когда выбрана вкладка "Все",ограничен список загружаемых сообщения, до 19 только. (пропадает "листалка" для сообщений) При работе на других вкладках - Общение, Дела, Мое - загрузка сообщения не ограничена.

Код подключения компонента

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent( 
    "bitrix:socialnetwork.log", 
    "", 
    Array( 
        "USER_VAR" => $arResult["ALIASES"]["user_id"], 
        "GROUP_VAR" => $arResult["ALIASES"]["group_id"], 
        "PAGE_VAR" => $arResult["ALIASES"]["page"], 
        "PATH_TO_USER" => $arResult["PATH_TO_USER"], 
        "PATH_TO_MESSAGES_CHAT" => $arResult["PATH_TO_MESSAGES_CHAT"], 
        "PATH_TO_VIDEO_CALL" => $arResult["PATH_TO_VIDEO_CALL"], 
        "PATH_TO_GROUP" => $arParams["PATH_TO_GROUP"], 
        "PATH_TO_SMILE" => $arResult["PATH_TO_SMILE"], 
        "PATH_TO_USER_BLOG_POST" => $arResult["PATH_TO_USER_BLOG_POST"], 
        "PATH_TO_GROUP_BLOG_POST" => $arParams["PATH_TO_GROUP_POST"], 
        "SET_NAV_CHAIN" => $arResult["SET_NAV_CHAIN"], 
        "SET_TITLE" => $arResult["SET_TITLE"], 
        "ITEMS_COUNT" => 999, 
        "NAME_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["NAME_TEMPLATE"], 
        "SHOW_LOGIN" => $arParams["SHOW_LOGIN"], 
        "DATE_TIME_FORMAT" => $arResult["DATE_TIME_FORMAT"], 
        "SHOW_YEAR" => $arParams["SHOW_YEAR"], 
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"], 
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"], 
        "PATH_TO_CONPANY_DEPARTMENT" => $arParams["PATH_TO_CONPANY_DEPARTMENT"], 
        "SHOW_EVENT_ID_FILTER" => "Y", 
        "SHOW_SETTINGS_LINK" => "Y", 
        "SET_LOG_CACHE" => "Y", 
        "USE_COMMENTS" => "Y", 
        "BLOG_ALLOW_POST_CODE" => $arParams["BLOG_ALLOW_POST_CODE"], 
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N", 
        "AJAX_MODE" => "Y", 
        "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "N", 
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N", 
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N", 
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y", 
        "CONTAINER_ID" => "log_external_container", 
        "SHOW_RATING" => $arParams["SHOW_RATING"], 
        "RATING_TYPE" => $arParams["RATING_TYPE"], 
        "AVATAR_SIZE" => $arParams["LOG_THUMBNAIL_SIZE"], 
        "AVATAR_SIZE_COMMENT" => $arParams["LOG_COMMENT_THUMBNAIL_SIZE"], 
        "NEW_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["LOG_NEW_TEMPLATE"], 
        "PAGE_SIZE" => 10, 
        "LOG_DATE_DAYS" => 365 
     ), 
     $component 
);
```

В параметрах компонента настроено кол-во выводимых сообщений 999. Подскажите, в чем дело?

Comment: В испорченной карме в связи с использованием битрикса? :)

Comment: Битрикс это как-то связано с Сатаной?

Comment: А это не очевидно? лично у меня, волей не волей, такое количество капса вызывает рвотный рефлекс :)